# How to leave from google meet call after specified time

Tags: python, selenium

I have been working on this script that automatically joins google meets. It logs in to gmail and then goes to the meeting automatically if it is the time for meeting. But, now I am having problems with leaving the meeting after certain time. I want to just close a browser tab, thus the meeting. Then continue checking for the next meeting. I think the last while loop that is intended to close the chome tab after the meeting is done does not run at all. I have tried replacing it with print statements to see if it is executed, but it does not. I do not know why not tho.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import datetime
import time
import signal

now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M / %A")

justtime = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print (current_time)


def Glogin(mail_address, password):
    #os.system("obs --startvirtualcam &")
    # Login Page 
    driver.get( 
        'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/&ec=GAZAAQ') 

    # input Gmail 
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys(mail_address) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click() 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 

    # input Password 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath( 
        '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(password) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click() 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 

    # go to google home page 
    driver.get('https://google.com/') 
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    driver.get(sub)
    # turn off Microphone 
    time.sleep(1)
    #driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JRY2Pb")[0].click()
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JRY2Pb")[0].click()
    # switch camera
    time.sleep(2)
    for x in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("JRtysb"):
        x.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("FwR7Pc"):
        a.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    for b in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("XhPA0b"):
        b.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.TAB + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    # Join meet 
    time.sleep(1) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(2000) 
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector( 
        'div.uArJ5e.UQuaGc.Y5sE8d.uyXBBb.xKiqt').click()
    
# assign email id and password
mail_address = 'email'
password = 'password'

# create chrome instamce 
opt = Options() 
opt.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
opt.add_argument('--start-maximized')
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 0, 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})

while True:

    if current_time == "05:00 / Wednesday":
        
        sub = "link"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver') 
        Glogin(mail_address, password)
        break
    
while True:
    if current_time == "05:01 / Wednesday":
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **time** module:

the fuction "time.sleep()" will pause the script.

and then you can go to the other meeting, if you change url of the tab you will leave the meeting.

```
import time

time.sleep(60)

driver.get(url)
```